# How to take text input in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am making a HTML5 game with Phaser, I want to take palyer name as input and save it for later use how can I do it with Phaser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen a Flash game with HTML overlayed to handle text. I expect as Javscript game engines grow, they will ultimately find they also need to handle rendering text inside the canvas. The good news is that the work has already begun. https://github.com/goldfire/CanvasInput

```
<script src="CanvasInput.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var bmd = this.add.bitmapData(400, 50);    
    var myInput = this.game.add.sprite(15, 15, bmd);

    myInput.canvasInput = new CanvasInput({
        canvas: bmd.canvas,
    });
    myInput.inputEnabled = true;
    myInput.input.useHandCursor = true;    
</script>
```

A Phaser and CanvasInput demo can be seen here, http://codepen.io/jdnichollsc/pen/waVMdB?editors=001

One downside is that you must use canvas rendering in Phaser using Phaser.CANVAS and not Phaser.AUTO.

**UPDATE**: someone made this too https://github.com/orange-games/phaser-input

Comment: thanks for the answer this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

there are a lot of options you can do but what about windows prompt

```
var player = prompt("Please enter your name", "name");
```

then you can save it via local storage

```
localStorage.setItem("playerName", player);
```

if you want to use it later

```
localStorage.getItem("playerName");
```

Comment: what should I do if I want to save player name and score in a database for later use.

Comment: you cant use database in javascript becuse it is client side language and you need to use php or node.js  
however i explained how to save it in player browser ind load it again using local storage if you found my answer is useful please up vote it and mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

In my game I used modal (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) to allow user input name. I also implemented leaderboard. To save users and scores (+times) I integrated with parse (https://www.parse.com/)

Working example: http://majery.pl/memo/

Comment: the example you are given here is great thats what I am looking for. can I have the source code please.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [CanvasInput](https://github.com/goldfire/CanvasInput) library. It creates native canvas-based inputs and is very easy utilize. You add it to your `create` method and continue from there. [Here's an example](https://codepen.io/jdnichollsc/pen/waVMdB?editors=001) of it being used with Phaser.